# who can create a persistent volume in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Its mentioned in kubernetes official website as below for PV and PVC.

```
A PersistentVolume (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator. It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual pod that uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.

A PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It is similar to a pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., can be mounted once read/write or many times read-only).
```

who is adminstrator here? when they mention it in persistent volume perspective?

Answer (score 1):

An administrator in this context is the admin of the cluster. Whomever is deploying the PV/PVC. (An operations engineer, system engineer, SysAdmin)

For example - an engineer can configure AWS Elastic File System to have space available in the Kubernetes cluster, then use a PV/PVC to make that available to a specific pod container in the cluster. This means that if the pod is destroyed for whatever reason, the data in the PVC *persists* and is available to other resources.

Comment: If i have permission to deploy any other image. will i have permission to create PV as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: There can be multiple layers to that question;

You will need access to either a) create a storage device in the cloud infrastructure you are using (AWS EFS for example) b) have someone create the underlying storage space

You can have restricted permissions via Kubernetes' RBAC if deployed in your cluster, but if that is not in place or you have the proper permissions, you can write a YAML file and then just `kubectl create -f`